# Stream reader to analysis computation times

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, analysis

I'm very new to C#, I'm trying to develop a program to analyze computational time. The simulations program's output gives me 4 files to 4 parts of the process. 
The form should present only the time in seconds (that's why i got regex.replace)

Here is some of my code , so far.
I got a error " Not possible to read form closed textreader"

```
 private void btn_read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string line;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Log operation A files (*.lga)|*.lgf|Log operation B files (*.lgb)|*.lgb|Log operation C files (*.lgc)|*.lgc|Log operation D files (*.lgd)|*.lgd|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path;
            path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            // Read the file and display it line by line. 
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("Computation Time for part A Analysis ="))
                    {

                        txt_t_a.Text = Regex.Replace(line, @"[^0-9.]+", "");

                    }

                    file.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TILOW.png)

[an example of the log file folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzbaE.png)

Comment: You are closing the file within the while loop `file.Close();`, did you want to do that within the `if` condition? You close the file and then in the next iteration you try to read from the file and that's why you get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing your reader while you're trying to read it, resulting in an error. The relevant code is below. Move the close and it should stop giving you that error.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
    line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("Computation Time for part A Analysis ="))
        {

            txt_t_a.Text = Regex.Replace(line, @"[^0-9.]+", "");

        }

        // Remove this line. 
        // file.Close();
    }
    // Put it here
    file.Close()
} 
// Or here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, what if i would like to read 2 variables at the same time? Should i declare 2 Streamreaders ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line:

`System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);`

And Update:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("Computation Time for part A Analysis ="))
                    {

                        txt_t_a.Text = Regex.Replace(line, @"[^0-9.]+", "");

                    }

                    sr.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, what if i would like to read 2 variables at the same time?
Should i declare 2 Streamreaders ?

Comment: If you need to associate the 2 files read, then you will need 2 StreamReader objects.

If the handling of one file is independent of the other, then you can use the same object.

And if you choose to run everything in parallel, you can use Threads.